# How to work with Profile Provider (.net) in desktop application?

Tags: c#, .net, desktop, profile

please help me, how can I get User's Profile from database storage?
Configurations of default profile provider I have in application's config...
How can I get Profile class, or ProfileCommon class?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I did not find a straightforward solution, but this problem can be solved using WebServices. This way I solved it well myself.